# Ubuntu "E: Unable to locate package mysql"

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Can't solve the problem because nothing helps. Try to install mysql but package is not found. gedit and some other packages looks the same.

Firstly repositories were with subdomain 'by.' (because of regional settings). But I changed them to main server without subdomain. Maybe this caused problems?

I use xubuntu 16.04 xenial xerus.

source.list is

```
# deb cdrom:[Xubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719)]/ xenial main multiverse restricted universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted    
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted    
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe    
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates universe    
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates multiverse   
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse    
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner    
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted    
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe    
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

`apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` doesn't help

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no package with the name of 'mysql' in the repositories.

If you would like to to connect other mysql servers, you need the mysql-client package: `sudo apt-get install mysql-client`.

If you want to host a database you need the mysql-server package: `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`.

Installation guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: This was immensly helpful. For those that didn't catch it: `mysql-client` is what you want if you want to use mysql, but while connected to a different database server. `mysql-server` actually runs the database on your current server. This is what I needed, i didn't want to install the whole mysql-server just to connect to an external database server, but i needed the mysql cli. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

then

> sudo apt-get install mysql-server

Answer (score -1):

Try using deb http://kali.download/kali/ kali-rolling main contrib non-free in your sources.list file.

Then run

```
apt update & upgrade
```

then run

```
apt install mysql-server
```

Comment: This sounds like a very bad solution - you're not installing the correct ubuntu package. Instead you're installing packages from an different Linux distribution.

Comment: Using a ppa is fine, but mixing in a whole repository for a different distribution will cause mayhem and you will run into dependency problems sooner than later.