# Unable to install MySQL in Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm trying to install the MySQL server by using the Ubuntu operating system package manager with following commands:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

and getting error as :
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql-server

I tried this *"[Ubuntu "E: Unable to locate package mysql"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41921180/ubuntu-e-unable-to-locate-package-mysql)"* but it was not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try running the command before installing`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: Yeah, I tried this also but still getting the same issue.